# How do I know infowindow has already popped up in google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I want to display some animation on infoWindow in google maps with jQuery.

```
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: contentString
    });
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
    setTimeout(animation, 1000);
    });
```

`animation()` has to get element by its id on infoWindow, so the infoWindow must finish loading before `animation()` is executed.

How can I execute `animation()` immediately afer infoWindow finish loading instead of waiting 1 second every time?

Comment: I don't actually know the answer but I would ask that infoWindow is a DOM object so it should trigger onload event that you could listen to

Comment: does .open accept a callback function? try infoWindow.open(map, marker, function(){ animation(); }); ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
google.maps.event.addListener(infoWindow, 'domready', function() {
      //do something
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if (infowindow.getMap()) { // TODO: }