# calling javascript in infowindow google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am trying to call javascript inside google map infoWindow(). I know it's a classic question. I have read a lot of similar question in stackoverflow butI  I can't find solution :(

my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE> 
<html> 
   <head> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://visapi-gadgets.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/termcloud/tc.css"/> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://visapi-gadgets.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/termcloud/tc.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script> 
   <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
   <title>Rectangle Overlay</title> 
   <style type="text/css"> 
   #map { 
   width:1200px; 
   height: 700px; 
   } 
   </style> 
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script> 
   <script type="text/javascript"> 
function init() { 
var myOptions = { 
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(38.122404, 23.862591), 
  zoom: 3, 
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP 
}; 
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),myOptions); 



  var locations = [
      ['Bondi Beach', 38.6391,23.3437],
      ["<scr"+"ipt type='text/javascript'>alert('test');</scr"+"ipt>", 37.893, 23.936999999999998]
    ];


 var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      })(marker, i));
    }



 } 
 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init); 
 </script> 
 </head> 
 <body> 
 <h1>Service</h1> 
<h2> Map <h2> 
 <div id="map"></div>  

    </script>
</td></tr></table> <div id="chart_div" style="width: 1800px; height: 1100px;"></div> </body> 
 </html>
```

anyone know how to solved this issue?

Thank you!

> EDIT:

The answer of [Jonas Grumann](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1254917/jonas-grumann/)is correct.
In fact the javascript that I need to run is to build a cloudword inside infowindow calling TermCloud() function . I try below code. Any idea please???

```
 <!DOCTYPE> 
    <html> 
       <head> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://visapi-gadgets.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/termcloud/tc.css"/> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://visapi-gadgets.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/termcloud/tc.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script> 
       <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
       <title>Rectangle Overlay</title> 
       <style type="text/css"> 
       #map { 
       width:1200px; 
       height: 700px; 
       } 
       </style> 
       <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script> 
       <script type="text/javascript"> 
    function init() { 
    var myOptions = { 
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(38.122404, 23.862591), 
      zoom: 3, 
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP 
    }; 
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),myOptions); 



      var locations = [
          ['Bondi Beach', 38.6391,23.3437],
          ["Hello", 37.893, 23.936999999999998]
        ];


     var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

        var marker, i;

        for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
          marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
            map: map
          });

          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {
              //infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
              infowindow.open(map, marker);
              var yourFunction = new YourFunction(locations[i][0])

            }
          })(marker, i));
        }


         var YourFunction = function(str) {
            this.init = function() {

          google.load("visualization", "1");
          google.setOnLoadCallback(draw);     

            }
            this.init();
        }

    function draw() {
            data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data.addColumn('string', 'Label');
            data.addColumn('number', 'Value');
            data.addColumn('string', 'Link');
            data.addRows(3);
            data.setValue(0, 0, 'First Term');
            data.setValue(0, 1, 10);
            data.setValue(1, 0, 'Second');
            data.setValue(1, 1, 30);
            data.setValue(1, 2, 'http://www.google.com');
            data.setValue(2, 0, 'Third');
            data.setValue(2, 1, 20);
            var outputDiv = document.getElementById('tcdiv');
            var tc = new TermCloud(outputDiv);
            tc.draw(data, null);
          }



     } 



     google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init); 
     </script> 
     </head> 
     <body> 
     <h1>Service</h1> 
    <h2> Map <h2> 
     <div id="map"></div>  

        </script>
    </td></tr></table> <div id="chart_div" style="width: 1800px; height: 1100px;"></div> </body> 
     </html>
```

Comment: Is the [infowindow domready event](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9532602/229088) what you are looking for?

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: no errors in the console

Answer (score 10):

Found a solution -- wrap the infoWindow content in a div and add a listener in the 'domready' event for that div's id (see this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3860277/google-maps-how-to-create-a-custom-infowindow)):

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: '<div id="myInfoWinDiv">'+ myContent +'</div>'
});

google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow,'domready',function(){
    $('#myInfoWinDiv').click(function() {
        //Do your thing
    });
});
```

In my example, a click handler is attached to the div using jQuery. You can put any JS in the domready event handler. It needs to be done in the infoWindow's domready, otherwise you can't be certain that the object has been created.

Comment: Too short for edit, but you're missing `);` after the second to last `}`.

Comment: Thanks for catching that, Goose

Comment: I hate to use comments for thanks, but I must say thank you. This answer has made my web game completely possible. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I think calling a function click listener should work (haven't tested it though):

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
      infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
      var yourFunction = new YourFunction()
    }
  })(marker, i));
```

Then, outside all the google maps stuff

```
var YourFunction = function() {
    this.init = function() {
        alert("You have clicked a marker");
    }
    this.init();
}
```

Comment: Thnak you for you answer!

But I have a new problem. see at edit!

Answer (score 0):

What about `click` event in Google Map API V3?

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: '<div id="myInfoWinDiv">'+ myContent +'</div>'
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(e){
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
    // Other stuff goes here...
});
```